# SuperLU library XCode issues

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv

I'm a newbie when compiling and adding 3rd party C++ libraries into XCode... So here's the problem. I have .cpp files wich depend on 3 libraries. OpenCV-Eigen-SuperLU. So far think that I managed to add correctly OpenCV-Eigen, but I got trouble adding SuperLU.

I'm really confused on where should I include source files paths??. Some tutorials say that I need to create a static lib... other that I need a framework... on the other hand there are XCode project template which just include src files into a folder inside XCode project's and then reference them from build setting properties. Anyway I really need some guidance here.

So here's my setup for most of the libs. I have a folder within the XCode project with all dependencies.

[image]

Then... on project build settings I setup header search paths-- and library search paths. To point that folder

[image]

Headers for SuperLU are found correctly... but I get Linker errors.

[image]
[image]
[image]

So as you can see, I have no idea what to do... I'm Sorry but as I told on beginning I'm a newbie adding libs into XCode... plus documentation of procedures it's not good at all. So if anybody could help me with some guidance or links where I can start understanding how the linking process works would be great.

I'm a little desperate at this point, os any kind of help would be really really great.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was advised to create a different target to compile all SuperLU as a pure c++ project with gcc compiler. That made it possible for iOS app to use the lib as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both SuperLU and Objective-C define YES and NO. So you get a conflict.